# How to pass props to all routes in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to pass `BASE_URL` to all components. My App.js is like:

```
<template>
<router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
import addJoke from './components/addJoke.vue'
import showJokesAll from './components/showJokesAll.vue'

export default {
   components: {
    'add-joke': addJoke,
    'show-jokes-all': showJokesAll
  },

  data () {
    return {
        BASE_URL : 'http://127.0.0.1:8090'       
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style> 
</style>
```

And the `routes.js`:

```
import showJokesAll from './components/showJokesAll.vue';
import addJoke from './components/addJoke.vue';

export default [
  {path:'/', component: showJokesAll, props: {BASE_URL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8090'} },
  {path:'/add', component: addJoke, props: {BASE_URL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8090'}  }  
]
```

and in `showJokesAll` component I have:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: 'showJokesAll',
        props: ['BASE_URL'],
      data () {
        return {
            jokes:[]            
        }
      },
      methods: {
      },

      created() {
        axios.get( BASE_URL + '/api/jokes').then( response => this.jokes = response.data);

    }
}
</script>
```

But the components  is not received `BASE_URL`.

> [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: BASE_URL is not
>   defined"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the prop define with props: ['BASE_URL'], you would use `this.BASE_URL`:

```
axios.get( this.BASE_URL + '/api/jokes').then(/*...*/)
```

Comment: Yes this works! Any idea how to get rid of the redundancy in the `routes.js`?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) file which contains data or a function which returns your BASE_URL and then import mixins file using,

```
import myMixins from './my_mixins.js'
```

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed” into the component’s own options.

If you want to manage the state of the data you should have a look at [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/).

> Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion.

**Updated:**

Also have a look a [Vue Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Simple-Example).

Comment: Doable, but overkill. AFAIK mixins are mostly for shared functions. What I want here is just to pass a string down to components. There should be more straightforward way to do so.